# When and what data should be cached?

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-cache

I want to know when should I cache data?

Should I cache `ListView`s? or `DetailView`s? What kind of data do I need to cache and does the amount of data matter?

When to cache?

When not to cache?

I want to know when should I decide to cache data?

**P.s**: I don't want to know how to cache, what I want to know is when to cache.

Answer (score 0):

its better to cache Base Information and do not cache transaction tables